# winforms connection properties dialog for configuration string

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, connection-string, database-connection

Is there a way to display the connection properties dialog for connection string browsing(for database) in run time?

As I want the user to be able to connect to various database using the GUI.
The same one as we get in visual studio connection properties dialog.

Thanks in Advance

[image: http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/c59e853019.jpg]

Comment: @Binary Please note that first word of my question is winforms,And its connection string for database.Thanks

Comment: Apologies, I've seen to get a spate of annoying "information lite" questions this morning. Apologies again for jumping the gun.

Comment: Are you aiming at only sql server or any database?

Comment: +1 Great question, I am surprised Microsoft haven't gone further with providing this dialog!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Look for [this](http://pedotnet.blogspot.com/2008/07/how-to-invoke-ole-db-data-link.html) article explaining exactly what are you looking for. What she say is the following:

1. You will need to add a couple references to your project:

   - OLE DB Service Component 1.0 Type Library
   - Microsoft ActiveX Data Objects 2.x Library
2. Use the following code:

   ```
   using MSDASC;
   using ADODB;

   private string BuildConnectionString()
   {
        string strConnString = "";
        object _con = null;
        MSDASC.DataLinks _link = new MSDASC.DataLinks();
        _con = _link.PromptNew();
        if (_con == null) return string.Empty;
        strConnString = ((ADODB.Connection)_con).ConnectionString;
        return strConnString;
   }
   ```

Comment: I recently went looking for the article in question and came across [this article](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/310083#bookmark-4) which from what I can tell has the same content as the original.

Answer (score 5):

I was looking for exactly that, and it appears that Microsoft has published the source for the Visual Studio connection dialog, so that it can be used outside VS :

I just tried it, it works fine :)

Update 7/2019

Since the Microsoft Code site is dark, and there doesn't seem to be an official Microsoft posting for `Data Connection Dialog`, here is a link to a Github user repository with the Microsoft code.

https://github.com/kjbartel/ConnectionDialog

[Original but now dead link  http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Connection](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Connection)

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if there exists a 'predefined' form for it, but, you could offcourse create your own form, and use one the [DbConnectionStringBuilder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.common.dbconnectionstringbuilder.aspx) classes ([SqlConnectionStringBuilder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnectionstringbuilder.aspx), [OracleConnectionStringBuilder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oracleclient.oracleconnectionstringbuilder.aspx), [OleDbConnectionStringBuilder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oledb.oledbconnectionstringbuilder.aspx)) to create the connectionstring from the parameters the user entered on your custom created form.

Comment: @Frederik Thanks but I believe that .net has provide the dialog .We are Just not being able to find it!

Comment: I assume the issue isnt just entering the details, but the MS dialog provides lookups, connection tests and (hopefully) exception handling!

Answer (score 0):

You can also use Universal Data Link Files

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e38h511e%28VS.71%29.aspx

Work with XP but I never tried it in Vista or Seven