# Is there a control or wizard for making an SQL connection similar to SSMS or Visual Studio's design-time functionality?

Tags: wpf, winforms

I want to create a small standalone app that would allow a user to be able to connect to a database that the user specifies. So I don't have to roll my own UI to grab input and build a connection dynamically, are there any controls or elements similar to what VS and SSMS use that will allow a user to select a database at runtime? I'm not picky about whether it's forms, WPF, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has already been answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2205993/winforms-connection-properties-dialog-for-configuration-string) for winform. I am not sure about equivalent version for WPF. However, if you are very particular about having it in WPF; then it's all about hosting winform (shall have the core logic for your dynamic connection string builder) within WPF.

Comment: Looks like the [Microsoft Data Connection Dialog on Nuget](https://www.nuget.org/packages/DataConnectionDialog) is the current home for this.

Comment: make sense as is been asked by folks on various instance.

Comment: vote to close if you wish, but I had difficulty searching.